# Non-trivial table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, formatting, multirow

I want to convert this OO table into latex:[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} %p{4cm} 
    \hline
      \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{Czas wykrycia} \\ \hline
Wymagania & Architektura & Programowanie & Testy & Po dostarczeniu  \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{.}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I don't understand why multicolumn is not centered and wide. This is my output:
[image]

Comment: You need to add the missing `& &` in the end of the row. You can't skip them even if they are empty. Also remove the empty line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a starting point for you

[image: screenshot]

Note that as @percusse said in his comment, you need to use alignment tabs even for columns that are empty. I've made use of the `\cline` command which stands for `column line` and has syntax

```
\cline{startingcolumn-endingcolumn}
```

so for example, `\cline{2-7}` draws a line from the 2nd column to the 7th column.

I've also loaded the `geometry` package just to enlarge the page size- you'll want to make sure it can fit inside your document.

For further reading, you might like to look at

- [`multirow`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/multirow/multirow.pdf) package which would help with spanning across multiple rows
- [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/caption-eng.pdf) to get rid of the `:` when your caption is empty (and also helps to customize captions globally)
- [`booktabs`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) to help make beautiful tables. A lot of folks would recommend omitting the vertical lines, but I'll leave that up to you

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Koszt naprawy}             &\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Czas wykrycia} \\ \cline{3-7}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}                          & Wymagania     & Architektura  & Programowanie & Testy     & Po dostarczeniu  \\ \hline
    Czas Wystapienia            &   Wymagania       &   1x          &   3x          &   5-10x       &   10x     &   10-100x \\\cline{2-7}
                                &   Architektura    &   -           &   1x          &   10x         &   15x     &   25-100x \\\cline{2-7} 
                                &   Programowanie   & -             &   -           &   1x          &   10x     &   10-25x  \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

For comparison, the *natural tables* mechanism of ConTeXt is very well suited for such tables (with spanning rows and columns). For example, the above table can be typeset as:

```
\starttext
\bTABLE[align=middle, width=fit]
  \bTR
     \bTD[nx=2, ny=2] Koszt naprawy \eTD
     \bTD[nx=5]       Czas wykrycia \eTD
  \eTR

  \bTR
     \bTD Wymagania        \eTD 
     \bTD Architektura     \eTD
     \bTD Programowanie    \eTD
     \bTD Testy            \eTD
     \bTD Po dostarczeniu  \eTD 
  \eTR

  \bTR
    \bTD[ny=3] Czas Wystapienia \eTD
    \bTD Wymagania              \eTD
    \bTD 1x                     \eTD
    \bTD 3x                     \eTD
    \bTD 5-10x                  \eTD 
    \bTD 10x                    \eTD
    \bTD 10-100x                \eTD
  \eTR

  \bTR
    \bTD   Architektura    \eTD
    \bTD   -               \eTD
    \bTD   1x              \eTD
    \bTD   10x             \eTD
    \bTD   15x             \eTD
    \bTD   25-100x         \eTD
  \eTR

  \bTR
    \bTD Programowanie   \eTD
    \bTD -               \eTD
    \bTD -               \eTD
    \bTD 1x              \eTD
    \bTD 10x             \eTD
    \bTD 10-25x          \eTD
  \eTR
\eTABLE
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: cool, nice demo!